# Where can I download Real time Traffic and weather data for the world?

Tags: transportation, dynamic, weather, global, real-time

Where can I  download real time data for traffic and weather? I'd like to use it as an overlay on a mapping service of my choice (eg. Google maps, OpenLayers etc.)

Comment: There is not one source for what you are requesting.

Comment: Weather can be retrieved from http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/pricing.html

Comment: you are likely going to want streamed data so you always have the latest for each. Unless you want a point in time. in which case archived data for this scope of area is going to be even harder to find.

Comment: In addition, are you looking for historical or live data?

Comment: I am ok with historical as well as real time data.

Comment: I think this should be two separate questions - one for traffic and one for weather. and there is no world-wide service for traffic info. even commercial & expensive sources don't cover the whole world.

Answer (score 3):

Parse (using python/etc) RSS feeds from local authorities. Tough, but free.

It's a bit of work up front, but then you can write the data directly into your own feature classes, and reserve yourself. Kind of like ESRI's new geoEvent processor Server extension, but all custom through python. I update my services every hour - so far so good. I pull about 500 stations every run, and preprocess a feature class with rss urls/ids linked to points.

Note: You mention 'for the world' - yikes - you may want to select the top 50 cities or so to begin!

eg http://rss.weather.com/weather/rss/local/USNY0996?cm_ven=LWO&cm_cat=rss&par=LWO_rss

Make sure they don't change their format!